# Is array access complexity O(1) or O(n) in perl?

Tags: perl, caching, complexity-theory

I'm caching the results of a function f(1), f(2), ..., f(1e7). Elements in the cache will be read randomly. In C I'd store this in a vector, since the access complexity is O(1). In Perl, should I store the cache in a vector or a hash?

I feel like storing it in a hash wouldn't take advantage of the fact that the input is sequential integers. But on the other hand, I'm probably overthinking this.

Comment: Is the performance difference measurable? What have you tried?

Comment: @GregHewgill Not in this case, but it would be with more elements if array access is O(n).

Answer (score 7):

Rather than cache the results of the function yourself, use the [Memoize core module](http://perldoc.perl.org/Memoize.html) that takes care of it for you.

```
use Memoize;
memoize('slow_function');
slow_function(arguments); # Is faster than it was before
```

That's all there is to it, and it's been around for a long time and is well-tested.

Comment: In general, if you're writing something in Perl that is generic to programming, and not specific to your very specific needs, there's already a module to do it.  Validating ISBNs?  Business::ISBN.  Parsing HTML?  HTML::Parser.  Regex to match (whatever)?  Regexp::Common.  On and on, if you need code to do it, it's probably on the CPAN.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the usual disclaimers about worrying about efficiency until you've profiled, I'd say store it in an array.  Hashes impose an additional overhead in computing a hash key.  Besides, arrays are the most natural representation, and unless you know your performance is off, go for clarity.

Comment: Performance is not just about speed, though the speed difference between a hash and an array is likely to be negligible in real code, it is also about memory.  One advantage to a hash is it is sparse, arrays are not.  If you do `$cache[3] = $value` and then `$cache[1_000_000] = $value` you have just allocated something like 8 megs for all the empty values in between.  This is not just wasteful, but a clever attacker can use it as a denial of service attack.

Comment: Excellent point to keep in mind in general, but the OP did say the input was sequential.

Comment: Sequential today, who knows what requirements tomorrow brings. Who knows who will maintain it and if they'll realize the limits of the design. Given how closely hashes and arrays perform, IMO it is not worth the risk. Even if it is loaded sequentially, it may be possible for a clever attacker (or normal user) to ask for `cached_function(1_000_000_000)` and consume all memory.

Comment: Well, hopefully whoever maintains it would know basic information about arrays.  Besides, only the OP is in a position to know if this is a likely extension.  It could be that the nature of the problem is such that sequential data is implied.  Whatever the case, your point about hashes being more appropriate for sparse data is well taken, and with the OP knowing this, s/he is in a better position to decide what's best for this project.

Comment: This presumes everybody is *careful* about everything they do and *carefully* and *slowly* read and study and fully understand all code before they act. In the long run, this strategy always fails. Furthermore, a maintainer may be using a function which calls this function and doesn't know anything about how its implemented (the point of functions). Finally, the OP may know things about the code which are true *now* but may not be true *later*. They may not be there to warn people, they may not even remember. Best not to leave land mines lying around for the sake of micro optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Both arrays and hashes in Perl are O(1). But, i bet O(1) for array is faster in absolute clock times. In case on sequental integers arrays may be way faster cus its simple index mathematic.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing array elements that exist is going to be faster than insertions into a hash. On the plus side, the performance of both scale similarly. (Complexity analysis measures how well something scales, not how fast it is.)

Worst-case access of array element:

```
$x = $a[$i];           # O(1)
$a[$i] = $x;   $i<@a   # O(1)
$a[$i] = $x;           # O(1), amortized
```

Worst-case access of hash element (for keys with a bounded length):

```
$x = $h{$k};           # O(1)
$h{$k} = $x;           # O(1), amortized
```

("Amortized O(1)" means it's O(N) for N of these operations.)

Given that your keys are sequential integers, you should most definitely use an array.

```
my @cache;
sub func {
    my ($n) = @_;
    return $cache[$n] //= ...;
}
```

If instead your keys were sparse, you'd be better off to use a hash to save memory.

```
my %cache;
sub func {
    my ($n) = @_;
    return $cache{$n} //= ...;
}
```

Comment: I was talking about access, not insertion. Much more time is spent accessing the cache than building it, in my case.

Comment: What do you mean by "amortized"?

Comment: Access is O(1). Adjusted. I did explain amortization.